# Android ListView not scrolling inside ViewFlipper

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I have A LinearLayout with a GridLayout inside. The GridLayout houses an ImageView, Textviews and then a ListView. I have tried all I can to get the ListView to scroll but it doesn't scroll at all. The LinearLayout ( Main One ) Is housed in a ViewFlipper if that changes anything.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/singleClub"
         android:weightSum="1">
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/mainclub_image"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/mainclub_name"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Genre"
            android:id="@+id/mainclub_genre"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Opening Times"
            android:id="@+id/textqView3"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="0"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Mon 00:00"
            android:id="@+id/mainclub_openingtimes"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="0"/>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_column="0">
                <ListView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/mainclub_listview"
                    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"/>
        </ScrollView>
    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I originally tried it with a Custom Expandable List View which worked but then stopped working later on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove scrollview outlining ListView and then set the height and width values of list view to match_parent. And Try using a relativelayout.

Comment: Still not allowing me to scroll. Any chance it could be due to the ViewFlipper taking the scrolling event and ignoring it?

Comment: I guess you need to create two separate xml files for ListView and ViewFlipper. Then you need to create a layout inflater inside your java file. Using the inflater you've to inflate the list view and use listview.addheader. I'll try to post the code.

Comment: ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.l);LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();ViewGroup H = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.header,lv, false);lv.addHeaderView(H, null, false);ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,arrayList);lv.setAdapter(adapter); note : the header contains your ViewFlipper.

Comment: Neither one worked, I went with a different ListView library code. Thanks all